# How do I fix the diagonal lines appearing on my imported OBJ file's faces?

Tags: objects, import

[image]I have an issue with importing .obj files to Blender. 
Once object is imported and I got to Edit Mode, the object has weird diagonals on it's surface (I add screenshot). So I can't edit it as a basic box object that is in Blender provided. How do I remove these diagonals and make this object normal one piece object. [image: strange diagonals object]

Comment: Nothing weird about it. The model in your .OBJ file got triangulated. Either you exported it with that option from whatever you used to export it or you simply downloaded it and it was already triangulated in the first place. Either way, it's not a Blender problem.

Comment: As menationed the mesh is triangulated. In case of simple model above try to use Convert Tris to quads operator with all tris to convert selected.

Comment: @metaphor_set  I managed to remove these diagonals. I converted them to quads, then in Edit Mode selected them and pressed X --> Dissolve Vertices. This solved my problem partly, as I still can't edit imported objects properly. I add one more screenshot for better understanding. On the left there is basic box, that is Blender object. On the right there is my imported object, that consists of different sides and edges, so I can't edit it as a basic box. How do I convert it to a one piece object then ?

Comment: It would actually help, if you tell us from where you get those files. If you are exporting them from Blender, you have to uncheck "triangulate" and probably "include edges". If you export them from somewhere else, you need to look for that stuff in the export settings there. **Either way - information is key. You won't get any answers, if you don't ask the right question.**

Comment: Besides - if it's only simple cubes like in the screenshots, you can easily reproduce them within minutes.

Comment: @metaphor_set I use Unreal Engine 4 (version 4.22) to create objects, then I export them to Blender. To export I select needed objects, go File --> Export Selected and choose .obj format and Save. UE4 actually doesn't offer any options while exporting .obj files. I also tried .FBX, this didn't work for me either. So I thought this issue with triangulatated meshes is Blender thing.

Comment: @metaphor_set Anyhow, it's not a problem to reproduce all the objects, but it would take some time. If this problem is not fixible, ofc, I'll have to switch to Blender, but I would like to continue working with UE4 as It's very comfortable for me to create levels there.

Comment: So I fixed my problem that object was divided into pieces. I just imported it with .fbx format, not .obj. That worked for me, now the object can be edited as basic Blender box.